# SVN :Want to create a SVN tag based on date b/w {2016-NOV-09} to {2016 -Nov-28}

Tags: svn

Hi I want to create a svn tag based on the above date.The svn command I am using is svn copy -r {2016-11-28} http://myserver/svn/project/trunk \
           http://myserver/svn/project/tags/tag-2016-11-28 \
           -m "Tagging project on 18th Jan 2011"

But I have some question
 1. the date entered in the Command, is this Last Change date.?
2. when I will use this command will it create tag from the date of creation of branch till the date that I  have mentioned .

Answer (score 2):

1. The version copied to make the tag will be the last revision created before 2016-11-28 00:00:00 - IOW, you're getting a copy of the versioned item(s) as it (they) existed  at that time.
2. No, it will not. A copy (or tag, which is the same in Subversion) is a reference to a **single point in time** and as such, it cannot represent a range of revisions. It can only represent the state of the repository at the time it was created, or the state as of the revision that was used to make the copy.